# APDU Write block commands on mifare card

Tags: c++, nfc, apdu, mifare

I have been trying to writing some data to my mifare classic cards. first I send these two commands which returns 90 00:

**Load Mifare Keys:**
FF 82 20 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF

**Authenticate:**
FF 86 00 03 05 01 00 05 60 00

now I'm  write commands to sector 0 and block 3 and block 4 by this commands
**APDU_WRITE_data_1 :** FF D  00 03 16
**APDU_WRITE_data_1 :** FF D  00 04 16

```
      // writedata1 in block 3 ...
//
    if (nres == SM_SUCCESS)// &&
    //bAPDURes )
{
    nlenrcv = sizeof(btRcv);
    nlencmd = 0;
    
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xFF;                // CLA
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xD6;                // INS
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x00;                // P1, Mifare Block Number MSB
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x03;                // P2, Mifare Block Number LSB
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 16;              // Lc, Data Length
memcpy(btCmd + nlencmd, btWrite_1, 16);
nlencmd += 16;

nres = m_Smart.RFTransmit(DEV_INTERNALRF, nlencmd, btCmd, (DWORD*)&nlenrcv, btRcv_1);

// writedata2 in block 4 ...

if (nres == SM_SUCCESS)// &&
    //bAPDURes )
{
    nlenrcv = sizeof(btRcv);
    nlencmd = 0;

    btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xFF;                // CLA
    btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xD6;                // INS
    btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x00;                // P1, Mifare Block Number MSB
    btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x04;                // P2, Mifare Block Number LSB
    btCmd[nlencmd++] = 16;              // Lc, Data Length
    memcpy(btCmd + nlencmd, btWrite_2, 16);
    nlencmd += 16;

    nres = m_Smart.RFTransmit(DEV_INTERNALRF, nlencmd, btCmd, (DWORD*)&nlenrcv, btRcv_2);
```

But it doesn't work
is it the APDU for writing wrong?

Comment: As you are dealing with pseudo APDU's you are instructing the card reader hardware to convert them to commands that the Card understands and as you don't specify the exact make and model of the card reader you are using it is difficult to help.

Comment: i'm using OMNIKEY Contactless reader and MIFARE card .. the code allows to do the write in blocks 2 but while doing this modification to do write in blocks 3 and 4 it doesnt work

Comment: You seem to authenticate to block 5 (= sector 1) while you try to write blocks 3 (sector 0) and 4 (sector 1). You will need to authenticate to the correct sector before performing a read/write operation.

Comment: is it this the right format APDU  ? CLA = FF

INS = 86

P1 = 00

P2 = 03 (Block Number for Authentication)

Lc = 05 (Length of Data Field)

Data Field = Version + AddMSB + AddLSB + KeyId + KeyNumber

Version=01

AddMSB=00

AddLSB=05 (Block Number)

KeyID=60/61 (60 for keyA and 61 for keyB)

KeyNo= 00 (Key Slot number of reader)  @MichaelRoland

Comment: No, P1 and P2 should be zero, see http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf